# PHP validate client signature using client public key

Tags: c#, php, signature, verify, phpseclib

Hi I'm building REST service and planning to erase language restriction for developing both client and server from this project, the REST server currently written using PHP.

For security I'm validating their hash code, and also their client app signature. Currently the hash is successful but for the signature it always failed.

Every client will have their own private key and on the server we will have their public key to verify the signature, each request to server will send a signature. 
If the client is a web server there will be only one private key for all user. If the client is a native app ( C# ) then each installed client app will have their unique private key.

PHP client to PHP REST server -> calculate hash ok, verify client signature ok
C# client (winapp) to PHP REST Server -> calculate hash ok, verify client signature failed

In the future I want to try with JAVA and vice versa.

I use easy way to create a self sign certificate

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out netclient.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -key netclient.key -out netclient.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey netclient.key -in netclient.crt -out netclient.p12
```

Here is my code to sign data using C#

```cs
public static string (string Base64EncryptedData ) {
X509Certificate2 my;
my = new X509Certificate2("cert/netclient.p12", "abcdefg", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;

csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)my.PrivateKey;

SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(Base64EncryptedData);
byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);

return Convert.ToBase64String(csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"))); 
}
```

It return a signature (base64) which I send to PHP REST server using GET method.
On PHP Server I recount the hash and verify but it never return 1. Currently I copy manually all the key to the server.

```php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR ."lib");
include("Crypt/RSA.php");

$p12cert = array();
$fp=fopen("cert/netclient.p12","r");
$priv_key=fread($fp,8192);
fclose($fp);
openssl_pkcs12_read($priv_key, $p12cert, "abcdefg");

//try using the phpseclib library from http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net
//req() will get all the $_POST, $_GET data req("signature") = $_GET["signature"];
//$hash_request is an base64_encode string same exact value as the one in C#
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->setHash("sha1");
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$rsa->loadKey($p12cert["cert"]);
$verified_phpseclib = $rsa->verify($hash_request, base64_decode(req("signature"))) ? "verified" : "diff";

//try using php built in openssl 
$verified_builtin = openssl_verify($hash_request, base64_decode(req('signature')), $p12cert["cert");
```

Non of the result return "verified" or "1"

Could it be because when C# sign the data, the format of the data is byte[] ?
Or is there other reason ?

I'm running all the code in linux 
php - using apache2
c# - using monodevelop

---

Here is my pk12 array after reading using openssl_pkcs12_read you can download it [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=BBB6B5E0F1EEB9B0!286&authkey=!AOIULEd4cKpAMG4)

```
Array
(
    [cert] => -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

    [pkey] => -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
)
```

Comment: My first guess is that the format of `$p12cert["cert"]` isn't correct. Is it a public key file or is it an X.509 cert? If the latter you can still use phpseclib but you'll need to first extract the public key from the cert using File_X509. Can you post a sample *.p12 cert so that I might test it out?

Comment: updated my post, including the certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR ."lib");
include('File/X509.php');

$p12cert = array();
$fp=fopen("cert/netclient.p12","r");
$priv_key=fread($fp,8192);
fclose($fp);
openssl_pkcs12_read($priv_key, $p12cert, "abcdefg");

$x509 = new File_X509();
$x509->loadX509($p12cert["cert"]);
$pubkey = $x509->getPublicKey();
$pubkey->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$verified_phpseclib = $pubkey->verify($hash_request, base64_decode(req("signature"))) ? "verified" : "diff";
```

Comment: It's my mistake apparently the hash is incorrect. using your method or openssl_verify actually works ok. Sorry for the trouble. I'm going to post all my finding here so other people can easily copy

Comment: @neubert Will you please explain all the variables in the code ? So that we can change according to our program.

Comment: I just adapted Wiryono Lauw's original code. Presumably the `req` function is his own. The original code attempted to do `$rsa->loadKey()` on the X.509 cert whereas my code does `$x509->loadX509()` on the X.509 cert and then gets the public key from that via `$x509->getPublicKey()`. Are there any variables in particular you're wondering about?

Comment: @neubert   Do you have any idea about **req** function ?